# Autotools: Autoscan forgets some checks

Tags: autotools

I am migrating a project to build it with autotools, and I use `autoscan` to get a template for `configure.ac` file.

I wanted to check if the generated `configure` script was testing some libraries headers, so I uninstalled the libraries I used in the project to test. For sure compilation fails because of missing headers but configure script didn't checked the presence of these headers before.

I checked the output file of `autoscan` and it seems that autoscan forgets some headers:

From `configure.scan`:

`AC_CHECK_HEADERS([fcntl.h limits.h stddef.h stdlib.h string.h unistd.h])`

All headers included in the project (`cat src/*.[c,h] | grep 'include <' | sort | uniq`):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <mosquitto.h> (library)
#include <owcapi.h> (library)
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
```

Why are libraries headers and other libc headers missing after autoscan ?

EDIT: It is the same for functions calls.

Comment: It's difficult to say.  The details of `autoscan`'s behavior are not documented, and you've (understandably) not presented the input on which you ran it.  If you really want to know, then I suggest putting in the work to reduce the problem to a [mcve].  If you do so effectively then you are likely to answer your own question in the process, but if not, or if you want to share, then you could post the results here.

Comment: As mentioned already, it's not entirely known how it chooses headers, but it's possible that `AC_CHECK_HEADERS` will encounter specific header names and run special [header portability checks](https://www.gnu.org/s/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Header-Portability.html). Note that page contains a broken link to the Gnulib manual's [ISO C and POSIX Header File Substitutes](https://www.gnu.org/s/gnulib/manual/html_node/Header-File-Substitutes.html) section (e.g. [`<fcntl.h>`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/fcntl_002eh.html)). Just a guess though…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that autoscan only includes checks for those C-language headers which are known to be missing or work differently on some (often obscure) compilers or platforms.

Headers which can always be assumed to be present, it won't check for.

Neither will it check for external library headers. You are expected to provide your own checks for those, often with pkg-config.